# Trying to enter the Fox's den

Tags: knowledge

You're trying to get into the fox's den, but the sneaky fox has devised a puzzle that deters drowsy dogs. Can you get in?

You find a panel with this writing:

> - B9
> - Q4
> - F14
> - C7
> - There is no void

What could the fox possibly mean?

> Reconstruct a well-known phrase. I hope your entire keyboard works!

Comment: This is so good. Wish I thought of the answer before giving in to looking at the ones below :P

Comment: ;D It's pretty easy. I'm thinking of releasing small puzzles every once and a while as I continue my TLL series.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Presumably the answer is

> **The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.**
>
>  where B9 indicates the B of "brown" is the 9th character in the phrase,
>  Q4 for the Q of "quick", F14 for the F of "fox", and C7 for the C in "quick".
>  There are no spaces (no void) - though it's not immediately clear if that means no spaces in the answer, or merely in the counting.
>
>  The hint is because this phrase contains all letters of the alphabet, so your whole keyboard needs to work to type it.

Answer (score 6):

The phrase is

> the well-known pangram, "**the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog**".
>
>  The numbers are indices, e.g. B9 means that B is the 9th letter etc.

Comment: I typed longer. ;)